# How to mock interface in Angular test case

Tags: angular, jasmine

In my Angular service ,  I am using an interface to fetch some values.
I am writing a test class for that service and want to mock the interface using useClass in Providers section.
I get an error 'AppConfigFake only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.' and 'IAppConfiguration' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
What is the work around for mocking interface.

```
fdescribe('MyDetails', () => {


  class ConfigServiceFake extends ConfigurationService {

  }
  interface AppConfigFake  extends IAppConfiguration {
    recall: string;
    customer: string;

  }
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyDetails  ],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [ {provide: ConfigService, useClass: ConfigServiceFake},
        {provide: IAppConfiguration, useClass: AppConfigFake}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();



});
```

Comment: Providing an `interface` for the `providers` array doesn't make sense. The providers array is for `services`.  Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: is there a reason you could not use the real interface but wrap it in Partial<..> ? We do that a lot so that we don't have to define all the possible real data

Comment: Please post code for the the unit under test.